# How can i get params value when i used NavigationActions.reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

App.js

```
const DrawerStack = DrawerNavigator({
  Dashboard: { screen: Dashboard},
  Pdfview: { screen: Pdfview},
  screen2: { screen: Screen2 }
})
```

Login.js

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'DrawerStack', params: { foo: 'bar' } 
    }),  
  ],
});
```

I try to get params value on Dashboard but i got undefined on Dashboard

Dashboard.js

```
 componentWillMount() {
   console.info(this.props.navigation.state.params)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should navigate to Dashboard Directly, instead of DrawerStack in routeName

```
const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Dashboard', params: { foo: 'bar' } 
    }),  
  ],
});
```

Comment: I used that but i am not able to open side menu if i used direct

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.foo
```